# Integrate PayPal Express Checkout with PHP

Tags: php, paypal

How can I integrate Express Checkout using PHP? Paypal's documentation is very poor on this subject.

Comment: You can find the sdk and example here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/nvpsoap-sdks/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML File - Make sure to replace Merchant ID. Also I've added useraction=commit so that the paypal pop up will display pay rather than a message about going back to the site to review payment.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" async></script>

<input id="amount">
<button id="paypal">Pay by PayPal</i></button>

<script>
    window.paypalCheckoutReady = function () {
        paypal.checkout.setup('REPLACE WITH MERCHANT ID', {
            environment: 'sandbox', # or production
            container: '#paypal'
        })

        $('#paypal').click(function () {
            var amount = $('#amount').val()
            if (amount) {
                paypal.checkout.initXO();

                var action = $.post('/paypal.php', {amount: amount});

                action.done(function (data) {
                    paypal.checkout.startFlow('https://www.paypal.com/checkoutnow?useraction=commit&token='+data.TOKEN);
                });

                action.fail(function () {
                    paypal.checkout.closeFlow();
                });
            }
            else
                alert('Please enter an amount')
        })
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

class.php - this is the class to run the paypal api calls

```
<?php

class PayPal
{
    private $config;

    private $urls = array(
        "sandbox" => array(
            "api" => "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp",
            "redirect" => "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr",
        ),
        "live" => array(
            "api" => "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp",
            "redirect" => "https://www.paypal.com/webscr",
        )
    );

    public function __construct($config)
    {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    public function call($options = [])
    {
        $options = array_merge($options, $this->config);
        return $this->_curl($this->api_url(), $options);
    }

    public function redirect($response)
    {
        $redirect_url = sprintf("%s?cmd=_express-checkout&token=%s", $this->redirect_url(), $response["TOKEN"]);
        header("Location: $redirect_url");
    }

    private function redirect_url()
    {
        return $this->urls[$this->config["environment"]]["redirect"];
    }

    private function api_url()
    {
        return $this->urls[$this->config["environment"]]["api"];
    }

    private function _curl($url, $values)
    {
        $curl = curl_init($url);

        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($values),
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
            //CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false //for dev
        );

        curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
        $rep = curl_exec($curl);

        parse_str($rep, $response);
        curl_close($curl);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

paypal.php - make sure to replace config with paypal account details. Also the example doesn't include any code to handle cancel.php - the file accessed when the user closes the pop up without paying

```
<?php

include('class.php');

$config = array(
    "environment" => "sandbox", # or live
    "user"  => "REPLACE WITH PAYPAL USER",
    "pwd"  => "REPLACE WITH PAYPAL PASSWORD",
    "signature"  => "REPLACE WITH PAYPAL SIGNATURE",
    "version"  => 113
);

$paypal = new PayPal($config);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $result = $paypal->call(array(
        'method' => 'SetExpressCheckout',
        'paymentrequest_0_paymentaction' => 'sale',
        'paymentrequest_0_amt' => $_POST['amount'],
        'paymentrequest_0_currencycode' => 'USD',
        'returnurl' => 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . 'paypal.php?amount=' . $_POST['amount'],
        'cancelurl' => 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . 'cancel.php?amount=' . $_POST['amount']
    ));
    if ($result['ACK'] == 'Success') {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($result);
    } else {
        echo 'Handle the payment creation failure <br>';
    }
} else {
    $result = $paypal->call(array(
        'method' => 'DoExpressCheckoutPayment',
        'token' => $_GET['token'],
        'payerid' => $_GET['PayerID'],
        'paymentrequest_0_paymentaction' => 'sale',
        'paymentrequest_0_amt'  => $_GET['amount'],
        'paymentrequest_0_currencycode'  => 'USD'
    ));
    if ($result['PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS'] == 'Completed') {

        $result = $paypal->call(array(
            'method' => 'GetExpressCheckoutDetails',
            'token' => $_GET['token'],
        ));

        //$result now contains customer information

        } else {
        echo 'Payment error';
    }
}
```

Good luck!